# How to redirect *all* output to a text file, except what you want to print to the terminal

Tags: bash, logging, terminal, io-redirection

I would like to learn how to clean up log output, and am starting by trying to deal with all the disparate forms of log output in a typical terminal window.

```
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions'...
remote: Counting objects: 100% (194/194), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (190/190), done.
[github stuff] ....
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://github.com/....pkg
######################################################################## 100.0%
[homebrew stuff] ...
Listening on port 1234...
[node.js stuff] ...
[rails stuff] ...
[python stuff] ...
[other stuff] ...
```

I would like to still keep this *potentially* useful log output in some file somewhere just in case, but instead to show the user something else, like this:

```
installing stuff...
starting node...
starting rails...
starting python...
....
```

How do I do this? How do I make sure that every single command I run in my bash script, the output is all centralized into a single log file, except that these few lines of human-readable text get printed to the terminal (and probably to the log file too).

Something like:

```
echo "installing stuff..."
run_command something >> log/terminal.log

echo "starting node..."
run_command something2 >> log/terminal.log
```

By **all** the output redirected, I mean stderr, stdout, etc., so nothing escapes to the terminal window except exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `exec` to redirect stdout and stderr for the remainder of the script. You can save the original stdout in another descriptor and write to that when you want to send to the user.

```
exec 3>&1 >log/terminal.log 2>&1

echo "installing stuff..." >&3 # this goes to terminal
run_command something # this goes to logfile

echo "starting node..." >&3 # this goes to terminal
run_command something2 # this goes to logfile
```

If you want the terminal output to go to the log as well, you can use `tee`

```
echo "starting node..." | tee /dev/fd/3 # this goes to terminal AND logfile
```

If you really want to write to the terminal, not the original stdout, you can write to `/dev/tty` instead of FD 3.

Comment: How do I turn it on for some commands and off for others? So I can, for example, tail some select logs in the process and output to stdout (I meant output to stdout when I said to the terminal).

Comment: Anything you want to go to the terminal uses `>&3`

Comment: This is not capturing **all** output. For example, `webpack` just output a bunch of build info logs like `[hardsource:developm] Writing new cache developm...`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `script` command? It saves all output of your terminal session (including the prompt) to a file. I don't think you can filter the data that gets written however, you'd have to grep through the log when you read it.

Comment: @alien `webpack` must be writing those messages to stderr, so you should redirect `stderr` as well. Do you know how to do that, or do you need me to edit the answer to show it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've updated the answer, but that should be explained in most shell tutorials.